# Angular and Firebase: How to retrieve UID of user with email address?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an angular app and use firebase for authentication.

One user has been registered so far:

[image]

How can I retrieve the UID of a user, if I only have the user's email?

So in this case the email is "john.doe@icloud.com" and I want to retrieve this user's UID from the angular app.

The following link describes how to do this for Node.js:

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users
```

But how can this be done for an angular app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no client APIs for Firebase Authentication to look up a user based on an email address.  If you'd like to expose this functionality to your app, you'll have to store user data in a database and query the database from the client.  Note that exposing this kind of query may have security implications for your app.